# The build is succeded on simulator but does not run on device

Tags: ios, swift, dtcoretext

I use DTCoreText framework. And when I try to run my app on device I get these errors:
[image]

I can not understand why this code works on simulator and does not work on device. Perhaps somebody can help me??

Comment: have you used that DTRichTextEditor in that Viewcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by going through the following steps:

1. Clean the project, including the build cache (Command-Option-Shift-K)
2. Removing the pod.lock file and the pods.xcodeproj files
3. And then closing Xcode
4. Delete drived data
5. running pod update again
6. Then building again

Comment: Thank u but sadly it didn't help.

Comment: So did you are using header file for `obj-c` file to use in `swift` ??

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue before, It was due to the Xcode problem. After installing the new Xcode the issue is gone away. Hope this helps you.